# How to run a react native program on android 10 in termux

Tags: android, npm, react-native, termux

I want to do both programming and running apps on my Android. So I am trying out termux. I have a working react native program that I wrote on Ubuntu.

I opened termux navigated to the program folder and did npm install. This is the output:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/lightBag_ExpoVersion2/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/lightBag_ExpoVersion2/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/lightBag_ExpoVersion2/node_modules/.bin/parser'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/lightBag_ExpoVersion2/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2021-03-20T09_47_18_096Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is `npm install --no-bin-link`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create symlinks in internal storage.
You have three options:
[1] use the --no-bin-link option. It works most of the time.
[2] move your project to termux data folder. Here, termux has more permissions like symlink, chmod etc
[3] root your phone and give termux superuser permissions. But this would be a complete overkill. I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

may be you have permission issue open terminal and try this command

`sudo npm install -g eslint`